# How do I include the device tree with my kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, device-tree

The purpose of the device tree is to "explain" the hardware to the kernel.

But if the kernel is "customized" for certain hardware, how do I "insert" the device tree into the kernel at build time(so there's not another "blob" floating around).

I'm targeting the 2.6.32.69 kernel, but anything else would be appreciated.

update -- found what may be the answer -- try it tomorrow -- make help says:

```
cuImage.<dt>    - Backwards compatible U-Boot image for older
                versions which do not support device trees
dtbImage.<dt>   - zImage with an embedded device tree blob
```

update2:  seems to work good.    I had a ppc board which ran 2.6.24 natively, and 4.3.3 built and ran with its own device tree.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my *limited* understanding goes, the device tree is a hardware description targeted at the (multitude) of ARM systems. It is still somewhat in flux, and working support is rather recent. I remember it started in Linux 3.x, 2.x is probably out. And the kernel has to be configured with it, new (4.x) kernels depend almost exclusively on it for configuration. But such a kernel might blow up on old hardware.

Comment: I'm using ppc systems -- the original was 2.6.24 -- 2.6.32.69 worked well with the embedded device tree.

The device tree is an interesting concept -- but when you have one kernel/one pierce of hardware, embedding it within the kernel is fewer things to break (IMHO)